# Does "AMD Ryzen 3 PRO 2100GE" (YD210BC6M2OFB) really exist?

Tags: cpu, amd-ryzen, amd-athlon

Such a processor is sold by a LOT of online stores throughout Eastern Europe (and at least a couple dozen pretend to have it on stock), see an example [here](https://m.onlinetrade.ru/catalogue/protsessory-c342/amd/protsessor_amd_ryzen_3_pro_2100ge_am4_oem_yd210bc6m2ofb-2840258.html):
[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7kJl.jpg)

However, searching by either the name or the product id on the AMD [site](https://www.amd.com/en/products/specifications/processors/) didn't get me anything; except for the `7nm` claim (LOL) repeated on most sites, the specs match most closely the ["AMD Athlon™ PRO 200GE" (YD200BC6M2OFB)](https://www.amd.com/en/products/apu/amd-athlon-pro-200ge) which, like all Athlon-labeled Zen 1 based processors does not support NVMe M.2 SSDs, which may be a very nasty surprise (even assuming that it's a genuine AMD processor).

So my question is: did AMD ever sell such a deceptively-named part through third-world countries, or is this simply a scam?

Answer (score 1):

My results of a search for "2100GE" on the AMD site are different, giving me 6 links -  https://www.amd.com/en/search?keyword=2100GE  Clicking on the Links mentions them specifically with "AMD Ryzen™ Desktop Processors with Radeon™ Vega Graphics Compatibility"

I also searched on Ingram Micro (in New Zealand).  Ingram Micro are a highly reputable multinational distributor of computer parts.  While they don't list the 2100GE for sale, searches for 21000GE show a single result - the 2200GE CPU.

Further, the performance tests on https://www.cpubenchmark.net/mobile/cpu.php?id=3452 - particularly coupled with the 1189 samples also evidence the distribution of the chip.

So yes, that chip did exist ,although I suspect only shipped to limited markets or specific OEMs - I could not find any boxed versions for sale on ebay ?     Looking further https://linustechtips.com/topic/1376841-amd-am4-ryzen-3-pro-2100ge/ suggest it was sold in limited quantities in HP systems.

Comment: So does it support M.2 drives? Crazy if it didn't.